# html2pdf: downloading pdf texts are overlapping and break the page

Tags: javascript, html2pdf

[image]
Currently, I am using the html2pdf library for downloading PDF files, it is working fine for me, but the problem is that after a few downloads the texts are overlapping and the complete page is broken. Using a pagebreak class I can restrict the page break issue but the overlapping issue and the broken page issue is still there. tried codes are

```
<div class="export-pdf" id="export-pdf">
      <div class="fullWidth page-min-height">
            Planned Procedure
      </div>
</div>

var element = document.getElementById('export-pdf');
var opt = {
            margin: [10, 0, 10, 0],
            pageNumber: true,
            pagebreak: {
                mode: 'css',
                avoid: '.breakPage',
                before: '.beforeClass'
            },
            filename: test.pdf,
        };
  html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save()
```

texts are overlapped I am expecting 'Planned Procedure'...if we have more data
  complete pdf text become overlap after a few downloads,

Comment: You should be posting code that can reproduce the problem, as well as images of the actual problem to better describe your question, in order to entice people who could help to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This function

```
 function genTablePDF(heightSize){
     html2canvas(document.getElementById("HTMLtoPDF"),{
       onrendered: function (canvas){
         var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
         var doc = new jsPDF();
         doc.addImage(img,'JPEG',5,8,200, +heightSize);
         doc.setPage(2);
         doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();
         var dateName = new Date();
         doc.save('PDF ( ' + dateName + ' ) ' +'.pdf'); // file name pdf
       }
     });
  }
```

in last parameter the variable is for height of the page

```
doc.addImage(img,'JPEG',5,8,200, +heightSize);
```

You can pass it through function heightSize OR you can use

```
heightSize = document.getElementById('pageSize').value
```

where document.getElementById('pageSize').value is giving the numbers of rows the the page table have or you can use your business logic like:

```
     var heightSize = document.getElementById('pageSize').value;
     if( +heightSize === 7 ){
        heightSize = 120;
     }
     if( +heightSize === 14 ){
        heightSize = 200;
     }
     if( +heightSize === 21 ){
        heightSize = 260;
     }
     if( +heightSize === 28 || +heightSize === 35 || +heightSize === 42 || +heightSize === 50 ){
        heightSize = 285;
     }
     doc.addImage(img,'JPEG',5,8,200, +heightSize);
```

I hope it is helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = document.getElementById('inner');
            var opt = {
                margin: 30,
                filename: this.auth_user,
                image: {type: 'jpeg',quality: 0.98},
                html2canvas: {
                    scale: 2,
                    bottom: 20
                },
                pagebreak: { mode: ['css'], padding : 200 },
                jsPDF: {
                    unit: 'mm',
                    orientation: 'portrait'
                }
            };

            html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).then(function() {
            }).save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Had also problems with overlapping text with safari browser. This fix helped: [GitHub](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/issues/213#issuecomment-480162459). "remove linebreaks from tags"

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution for overlapping in downloaded pdf.

Please use CDN for font-family

```
<!-- Include the Roboto font -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.4.0/font/Roboto/normal.js"></script>


and in script below changes

<script>
window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
function Convert_HTML_To_PDF() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    
    // Load the Roboto font
    doc.addFont('Roboto', 'normal');
    
    // Set the font for the document
    doc.setFont('Roboto');

    // Set font size
    var fontSize = 16;
    doc.setFontSize(fontSize);
    
    // Source HTMLElement or a string containing HTML.
    var elementHTML = document.querySelector("#printReport");

 // Set the font size for the HTML element
    elementHTML.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';

    // Use the specified font in the HTML to ensure consistency
    elementHTML.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto';
    
    doc.html(elementHTML, {
        callback: function(doc) {
            // Save the PDF
            doc.save('report.pdf');
        },
        margin:[15,5,25,5],
        autoPaging: 'text',
        x:0,
        y:0,
        width: 200, //target width in the PDF document
        windowWidth: 1000 //window width in CSS pixels
    });
}
</script>
```